# Google PubSub to BigQuery not writing JSON

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Ahoy,

I am trying to send data from Pub/Sub to BigQuery using the standard `PubSub to BigQuery` template. I have published some messages to the Topic but if I have a nested JSON, it fails, i.e. goes to the error table, with the following error:

`{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"event_data_decrypted","message":"This field: event_data_decrypted is not a record.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}`

The example JSON I sent to Pub/Sub is this:

```
{
    "event_id": "958dc0a1-40e0-458f-9ea0-3c231ca0c986",
    "event_name": "labeled",
    "event_time": "2022-03-22T14:19:48.514Z",
    "prescription_id": "332634da-85a9-4ffe-b856-a3b05f25d9d9",
    "event_data_decrypted": {
        "PrescriptionDate": "2022-03-23T00:00:00",
        "OrganisationId": 1,
        "PrescriptionSourceType": 10,
        "EpsTokenId": "6bc5688a-c085-49f1-93bc-e080ed979544",
        "TokenId": "6bc5688a-c085-49f1-93bc-e080ed979544"
    }
}
```

However, if I don't send a nested JSON, like the following, it works fine and I see the data in the valid BigQuery table:

```
{
    "event_id": "958dc0a7-40e0-454f-9ea0-3c231ca0c986",
    "event_name": "labelled",
    "event_time": "2022-02-22T14:19:48.514Z",
    "prescription_id": "332637da-85a9-4ffe-b856-a3b05f25d9d9",
    "event_data_decrypted": "Eeeesh!"
}
```

The target table exists and has the following schema:

[image: Schema definition]

Other than having to write a separate function/program or editing the template's JS UDF, is there any easier way to fix this? BigQuery isn't letting me create a JSON datatype column. I thought that might have helped. This should be simple and achievable, right?

Thanks in advance folks.

Comment: Make sure to match the schema of your table, the column `event_data_decrypted` should be of type record and within that you should have the other column names defined same as your JSON structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column is of type string and a string is expected. In your case it's JSON, not a string, that's why it failed.

As you can see in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#pubsub-subscription-to-bigquery) you can customize the PubSUb message processing with UDF. It's not perfect but it's a nice way to solve your issue.

JSON datatype is very new, and I assume it's not yet supported by the dataflow template.

Comment: Thanks for this. That's what I ended up doing and it turned out to be much simpler than I had originally though. A simple line of code fixed the issue and I don't have to set a specific record schema in BigQuery:
`obj.event_data_decrypted = JSON.stringify(obj.vent_data_decrypted)`
This way, I can just get a string JSON and then parse it later in BigQuery without having to worry about the JSON contents and key list.